# python socket and recv() returning empty data

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, recv

I have a c program that connects to a python server, sends a short string (less than about 100chars) and then closes socket.  It does this at a periodic rate.

The python server accepts connection, spawns a thread, and in that thread calls:

```
data = sock.recv(4096)
```

data often turns out to be empty.

After reading through the python man pages, and some of the stack overflow posts (thanks guys!), I realize that the problem is the c program that opens, writes, closes, sockets so quickly, that by the time the python server accepts, spawns thread, the recv() returns no data, as documented.

The problem is, I don't know a workaround to this problem?  I have very little control over the c-program.  Is where a way to tell python to buffer the message for recv() even if the other side closes connection?

(caveat: I haven't verified my hunch yet on wireshark, but the logs in both programs strongly indicate the c-program closes before recv() is even called for *most* of the time.)

thanks.

Comment: You should still receive all the data sent, even if the other side has closed the socket. There's a good chance your python program is mishandling some case. You should receive every byte of data the other end sent.

Comment: Thanks David.  I'll check for that.  There's about 10 connections the server has to handle, but the accept/spawnthread/read loop serialize on one lock, so effectively all 10 connections are handled serially.  I'm trying to figure out why the original author wrote it this way.  Anyways, this input is very valuable.

Comment: Its possible that the C program sets SO_LINGER to 0 then sends/closes right away. This is a great way to loose data kinda like you describe except that the server should see a RESET, not just no-data.

Comment: @BitDiot - at least the lock will make it easy to remove the thread spawn completely.